# Cannot find dequeue count for Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

A **Microsoft.WindowsAzure**.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage object has a **DequeueCount** property, but I cannot find a corresponding property on a **Microsoft.Azure**.ServiceBus.Message object.

Can anyone provide me with any info about where I might find this info?

Cheers
Craig

Answer (score 0):

It is available in [`Message.SystemPropertiesCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.systempropertiescollection?view=azure-dotnet) Class. The property name is [`DeliveryCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.systempropertiescollection.deliverycount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Message_SystemPropertiesCollection_DeliveryCount).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.  That looks like what I'm after.  I couldn't find that info anywhere.  MessageProperties (or just Properties, given it's a Message object) would have been a more appropriate name considering the type of detail it contains.